# display a raw image on screen-QML

Tags: qt, qml

i have raw image buffer. and i want to display it on qml screen.
should i convert that image into any image format and then display it on screen? or is there any way to display the raw image buffer on screen using QML?
when i tried doing it in normal way i got an error saying :

```
QML Image: Cannot open: file:///ui_cutebox_mips/1_1.raw
```

code:

```
Image{
...
source: "1_1.raw"
}
```

How can i display a raw image on screen? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have 3 options as I can see:

If you are not familiar with qtdeclarative source code and qtbase source code:

1. You have to convert it to some format that is supported by qt, like jpg, png, bmp.

If you are familiar with qt source code you can:

1. Implement an QQuickImageProvider to support RAW image format. you have to read specs on RAW format and write code by yourself
2. Add support of RAW format to QImage class in qtbase

I think I might have misunderstood you. If you are talking about raw image buffer like you have a binary file with pixels, then you still have the same options. You'll have to put you image buffer as ImageData to QImage in your ImageProvider when creating a QImage.